# Caption and tablenotes in two columns (in threeparttablex)

Tags: captions, footnotes, multicol

I have a table with a long caption and footnotes on a landscape page, prepared using `ThreePartTablex`, but it does not fit. I'm now looking for options to make it fit. My best idea so far was to set both caption and footnotes in two columns. However, I have no idea how to do this for the caption and if using the `multicols` environment for the tablenotes, the distance from the table is too large.

This is an example of what I've tried so far:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[headsepline, footsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings} %using scrpage2 to highlight typearea   
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape} % automatically rotates the pdf on landscape pages
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ThreePartTablex}    % as I'm also using longtabu in another section, I'm using the x version of the package
\usepackage[format=plain, font={small}, labelsep = space, width=0.9\textwidth]{caption} 
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table} % to force everything onto one page
    \centering
\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \caption{My caption is quite long and uses multiple lines. \\ \blindtext }
    \rule{20cm}{9cm} %This table is actually in a separate pdf, thus I'm using a box here to represent it.
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \footnotesize
        \item[a] First item
        \item[b] Another item
        \item[c] Another item
        \item[d] Another item
        \item[e] Another item
        \item[f] Another item
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{multicols}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

I'm also happy to hear about possible other solutions that might be cleaner and/or look nicer, but spreading the table over multiple pages, for example, is not really an option as it presents an overview.

Answer (score 3):

I've no idea how to do this for the caption, but for the tablenotes it's quite easy: before `\begin{multicols}{2}` you need `\setlength{\multicolsep}{0cm}` (or some other small value)
I actually have:

```
\begin{tablenotes}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.8cm}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{0cm}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \item[a]An item (footnote
    \item[b]Another item (footnote)
    \item[c]From reference \cite{ref_1}
    \item[d]From reference \cite{ref_2}
    \item[e]From reference \cite{ref_3}
    \item[f]From reference \cite{ref_4}
    \item[g]From reference \cite{ref_5}
    \item[h]From reference \cite{ref_6}
  \end{multicols}
\end{tablenotes}
```

putting the `multicols` inside the `tablenotes`.