# Two-column text within a caption environment

Tags: captions, memoir, two-column, landscape

I have a particularly wide figure with a particularly long caption that I've lovingly put in a `landscape` page in a `memoir` document with `pdflscape`.

As the figure is relatively thin and wide, and the caption is also wide, I want to have two columns of text to enhance readability. However, neither `multicols`, `\twocolumn` or anything else I've tried (including a `mbox`) let me style the caption in this fashion, and just produce a large number of cryptic error messages.

The MWE that reflects what I'm trying to do is below. The [only similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135284/caption-and-tablenotes-in-two-columns-in-threeparttablex) I can find on Tex.SE has an answer that starts 'I have no idea how to do this for captions'!

```
 \documentclass{memoir}
 \usepackage{geometry,pdflscape,afterpage}
 \usepackage{lipsum,mwe}
 \begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\afterpage{
\clearpage
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-16x9}
\caption{\textbf{A very, VERY long caption:} Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at, tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy pellentesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fermentum massa ac quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat magna. Nunc eleifend consequat lorem. Sed lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pel- lentesque tincidunt purus vel magna. Integer non enim. Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Donec bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi. Nam vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu massa.}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 \documentclass{memoir}
 \usepackage{geometry,pdflscape,afterpage}
 \usepackage{lipsum,mwe,multicol}
 \begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\afterpage{
\clearpage
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-16x9}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\caption[]{%
\textbf{A very, VERY long caption:} Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at, tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy pellentesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fermentum massa ac quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat magna. Nunc eleifend consequat lorem. Sed lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pel- lentesque tincidunt purus vel magna. Integer non enim. Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Donec bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi. Nam vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu massa.}
\end{multicols}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, with `adjustbox`

```
 \documentclass{memoir}
 \usepackage{geometry,pdflscape,afterpage}
 \usepackage{lipsum,mwe,multicol}
 \usepackage{adjustbox}
 \begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\afterpage{
\clearpage
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-16x9}
\caption[]{%
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\linewidth,valign=t}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\textbf{A very, VERY long caption:} Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at, tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy pellentesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fermentum massa ac quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat magna. Nunc eleifend consequat lorem. Sed lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pel- lentesque tincidunt purus vel magna. Integer non enim. Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Donec bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi. Nam vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu massa.
\end{multicols}
\end{adjustbox}}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that you need to put the optional argument for caption like `\caption[]{..`. I have used it as empty.

Comment: The presence of the optional argument for `\caption` is key, as is the positioning of `multicol` _before_ `\caption' when just using it, but _within_ caption if defining a separate page environment. Both points I missed. Thank you!